Ergodic theory on recursive squaring in binary
Suppose we have a number a with binary representation of $a=v_l*2^l+v_{l-1}*2^{l-1}+...v_0$ where $v_0=1$ and not all $v_r=0$ for r>0
if we take $a_0=a$ and $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2$   does correlation between $v_n$ and $v_m$ go to 0 as well as $v_r$ in both $a_k$ and $a_{k+s}$ as  k$\rightarrow \infty$? in other words do the bits become independent from the previous past bits as well as other bits?
